# Git: Pulling a rebased branch

Tags: git, push, rebase, pull

Let me describe my situation:

Mr Blond and Mr Orange are working on branch A that branches out of the master branch on commit M1. Branch A has 2 commits: A1 and A2.

```
M1  
   \
    \
     A1 - A2
```

Meanwhile, Mr Orange committed and pushed 2 more commits on the master branch, M2 and M3.

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \
    \
     A1 - A2
```

Mr Blond pulls from the remote, and after a while decides to rebase onto the master branch:

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \         \
    \         \
     A1 - A2   A1` - A2`
```

Now A1` and A2` are the rebased commits that exist locally at Mr blond's, and A1 and A2 exist remotely. Mr Blond pushes his commits, using **-f** to force his changes and "rewrite" history. Now the remote repository looks like this:

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2`
```

But Mr. Orange worked on the A branch as well. His local repository still looks like this:

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \
    \
     A1 - A2
```

What does Mr. Orange need to do in order to be synchronized with A branch in the remote repository?

A normal pull won't work. Will **pull -f** force the changes from the remote locally? I know that deleting the local version of A and bringing it again from the remote repository will do the trick but that doesn't seem to be a good way to achieve that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My recommendation (or, "what I would do if I were Mr Orange") is, start with `git fetch`.  Now I'll have this in my repo, which is what Mr Blond had after his rebase and just before he ran "git push -f".

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \         \
    \         \
     A1 - A2   A1' - A2'
```

The one important difference is, I'll have my local label `A` pointing to rev A2, and the remote label `remotes/origin/A` pointing to A2' (Mr Blond had it the other way around, local label `A` pointing to A2' and `remotes/origin/A` pointing to A2).

If I've been working on my copy of the branch named "A" I'll have this instead:

```
M1  ---- M2 ---- M3
   \               \
    \               \
     A1 - A2 - A3    A1' - A2'
```

(with my local label pointing to A3 rather than A2; or A4 or A5, etc, depending on how many changes I have applied.)  Now all I have to do is rebase my A3 (and A4 if needed, etc) onto A2'.  One obvious direct way:

```
$ git branch -a
  master
* A
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/A
$ git branch new_A remotes/origin/A
$ git rebase -i new_A
```

and then drop revs A1 and A2 entirely, since the modified ones are in new_A as A1' and A2'.  Or:

```
$ git checkout -b new_A remotes/origin/A
$ git format-patch -k --stdout A3..A | git am -3 -k
```

(the `git am -3 -k` method is described in the `git-format-patch` manual page).

These do require figuring out what I have that Mr Blond didn't before he did his `rebase`, i.e., identifying A1, A2, A3, etc.

If the second approach is successful I end up with:

```
M1  ---- M2 ---- M3
   \               \
    \               \
     A1 - A2 - A3    A1' - A2' - A3'
```

where my branch name `new_A` points to A3' (my existing `A` branch still points to the old A3).  If I use the first approach and it succeeds, I end up with the same thing, it's just that my existing branch name `A` will now point to A3' (and I have no name for the old branch with A1-A2-A3, even though it's still in my repo; finding it requires going through reflogs or similar).

(If my A3 needs modification to become A3', both the interactive rebase and the "git am" method will require work by me, of course.)

Of course it's also possible to just `git merge` (as in the answer by Gary Fixler), but that will create a merge commit ("M" with no number, below) and keep revs A1 and A2 visible, giving:

```
M1  ---- M2 ---- M3
   \               \
    \               \
     A1 - A2 - A3    A1' - A2' -- M
                 \_______________/
```

If you want to preserve the original A1 and A2, this is a good thing; if you want to get rid of them, it's a bad thing.  So "what to do" depends on "what you want the result to be".

Edit to add: I like the format-patch method better as it leaves my old A branch name around while I make sure everything is good.  Assuming it all works and *is* good, here's the last few steps:

```
$ git branch -m A old_A
$ git branch -m new_A A
```

and then, if old_A can be abandoned entirely:

```
$ git branch -D old_A
```

or, equivalently, start with the branch delete, then rename new_A to A.

(Edit: see also `git rebase --onto` documentation, for the goal of rebasing A3, etc., onto the new_A branch.)

Answer (score 131):

If Mr. Orange doesn't mind losing his changes, he can fetch from the server, then checkout the the branch:

`git checkout A` to get onto his local `A` branch.

Then, assuming the remote is named "origin", reset your local branch in favor of the remote branch:

`git reset --hard origin/A`

If he is concerned with losing changes, he can merge the server's changes in to resolve them (from his own `A` branch, and presuming again that the remote is named "origin") with `git merge origin/A`. This will make a new commit that's on top of both his and the remote's `A` branches with the changes from both merged together. Then this can be pushed back to the remote.

Comment: Note: there is no whitespace between `--` and `hard` - it took me a while, as the answer was wrapped on my screen precisely between those two:)

Comment: If there are no changes to track, it might also be just as easy to delete the local branch; fetch from the remote; and then checkout the newly fetched branch again.

Comment: I like this solution, especially when you may have already fetched updates from the origin, so it just resets the local ref for the branch without making another network request.

Comment: That should probably be `origin/A` not `origin/A2` since `A2` referred to a commit, not a branch.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. "git pull --rebase" can handle the situation just fine.

Comment: I guess that you need `git fetch` to download changes from the remote, before `git reset`, or that's not needed?

Answer (score 37):

#### TLDR

Unless I have misunderstood the question, the answer is for Mr Orange to `git pull --rebase`.

#### Longer read

##### Simple case

If we assume that the changes made by A1 and A2 are the same as A1' and A2' (even if their commit hashes aren't the same) then Mr Orange can go from having

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \
    \
     A1 - A2
```

locally to having

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2`
```

by either doing

```sh
git pull --rebase
```

or

```sh
git branch -d A
git checkout A
```

#### A more interesting case

If we assume, as above, that the changes made by A1 and A2 are the same and that Mr Orange has made an extra commit then he will locally have

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \
    \
     A1 - A2 - A3O
```

and origin will be

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2`
```

and, again, Mr Orange can get to

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2` - A3O
```

with

```sh
git pull --rebase
```

#### A more realistic case

If we assume, as above, that the changes made by A1 and A2 are the same, that Mr Orange has made an extra commit and that Mr Blonde has made an extra commit then Mr Orange will have this locally

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \
    \
     A1 - A2 - A3O
```

and, assuming Mr Blonde has pushed, origin will be

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2` - A3B
```

and Mr Orange can get to

```
M1  - M2 - M3
             \
              \
               A1` - A2` - A3B - A3O
```

by doing

```sh
git pull --rebase
```

though, this time, he may need to fix conflicts.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I don't know if Git improved so much since Gary Fixler's answer from 2013, but nowadays it doesn't seem to be an issue anymore to rebase a published branch.

Comment: That works for me. I have a fork where I rebase my branch on the moving master. `git pull--rebase` detects the update and, if no extra commits exist locally, all is resolved.

Answer (score 23):

I develop concurrently on two virtual machines, for configuration purposes. As a result, I frequently rebase on one machine and need the changes to appear on the other without difficulty.

Suppose my branch is named `feature/my-feature-branch`.  After finishing the rebase on the first VM, I do a git fetch on the second. The following message appears:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/my-feature-branch
Your branch and 'origin/feature/my-feature-branch' have diverged,
and have 21 and 24 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Well, don't do a git pull, because then you end up with a meaningless merge commit after quite a bit of fussing.

Instead, run

`git rebase -i origin/feature/my-feature-branch`

Once the text editor pops up, delete all commits, and replace it with the following (this makes it so the rebase completes without any commits being kept).

`exec echo test`

If you do have commits that need to be kept, then those can be applied here. In either case, the rebase will complete, and now both machines are in sync again, as evidenced by:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. I would like to point out that you may also choose to "drop" all of the commits in the last step, instead of running `exec echo test`, not that it makes any difference than deleting the commit lines.