# Single quote usage for example Git commit refs in documentation

Tags: git

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773249/git-pulling-a-rebased-branch), has the following diagram

```
M1  - M2 - M3
   \         \
    \         \
     A1 - A2   A1' - A2'
```

What does the single quote on A1 and A2, i.e. `A1'` and `A2'`, in this context mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a symbol borrowed from the mathematical notation of a [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative).

`A1'`, in this example, is the result of [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) `A1` on top of `M3`. While they will probably have the same body and same commit message (assuming there were no merge conflicts during the rebase), they have different parents (`A1'`s parent is `M1` and `A1'`'s parent is `M3`), and thus they are **not the same** commit, and do not have the same commit hash. `A1'` is **derived** from the original `A1`, and this common mathematical notation is used to highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a convention to indicate that commits have been [rebased](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) or cherry-picked. `A1` and `A1'` have the same content, but different parents and commit IDs. In this case `A1` and `A2` have been rebased onto `M3`.

`'` is the symbol for "[prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)#Use_in_mathematics.2C_statistics.2C_and_science)". `A1'` means it is derived from `A1`. You'd read `A1'` as "A one prime".